# Interpretation of Velocity addition theorem

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, velocity

For a primed frame that is travelling with speed $v$ in the postive $x$-direction relative to the unprimed frame.

The transformation of velocity is the following:

> [image: 1]

I understand the mathematical steps behind the derivation of this equation.

However, I am having trouble understanding the physics.

My main concern is what are the $y$ and $z$ components transformed as well. Since the relative velocity is only in the $x$ direction. What is the physical reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 3):

> My main concern is what are the y and z components transformed as well. Since the relative velocity is only in the x direction. What is the physical reasoning behind this.

Remember what we are describing here. We have two reference frames and one object. We know the velocity of the object in one frame and we wish to find the velocity of the object in the other frame.

We require the reference frames to be oriented such that the relative velocity between the frames is only in the x direction. However, having done that, the velocity of the object is not necessarily only in the x direction. So the other components represent the velocity of the object which may not be aligned in any way with the relative velocity of the frames.

Comment: Why do we want the relative velocity between the frame to be only in the x-direction. Why is the 'transformation of velocity' which is shown above derived on the assumption that the relative velocity is only in the x-aixs. I thought this was the general equation for any relative velocity. What is the general 'transformation of velocity' for any direction.

Comment: @PhysicsQuestion I don’t think that, in general, we do want the relative velocity to be only in the x-direction. That is simply what the author chose to write down here. I don’t know the fully general formula. You could derive it from this by adding a pair of spatial rotations, one to align the axes and the second to restore the original orientation.